# How toFind the absolute max and min values of a multivariable function bounded by a circular boundary

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, systems-of-equations

so as shown below in the image, the qustion is to find the max and min for the given function. The thing that i am not getting is why did the auther not consider the following:

1) $x =0$ or $ 2x+3y^2$ if $x=0$ here then $y= sqrt(2/3)$ and so is for the second equation when $y=0$ then $x=sqrt(1/2)$

2) how did he arrive at $8e{^4}<g(x,y)< 12e^{-4}$

[image: The Question]

Comment: Hey, what book is this if you don't mind sharing? I would like to see more of these things because I am studying them too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$g_x = 2xe^{-x^2-y^2}(2 - 2x^2 - 3y^2)$$

$$g_y = 2ye^{-x^2-y^2}(3 - 2x^2 - 3y^2)$$

If $x,y$ are both zero, it's immediate that $g_x = 0$ and $g_y=0$, hence $(0,0)$ is a critical point.

Suppose $(x,y)$ is a critical point with $x \ne 0$. Then

\begin{align*}
&x \ne 0\\[4pt]
\implies\; &2 - 2x^2 - 3y^2 = 0&&\text{[since $g_x = 0$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\; &2x^2 + 3y^2 = 2\\[4pt]
\implies\; &2x^2 + 3y^2 \ne 3\\[4pt]
\implies\; &3-2x^2 - 3y^2 \ne 0\\[4pt]
\implies\; &y = 0&&\text{[since $g_y = 0$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\; &2x^2 = 2&&\text{[since $2x^2 + 3y^2 = 2$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\; &x = \pm{1}\\[4pt]
\implies\; &(x,y) = (\pm{1},0)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Thus, the points $(\pm 1,0)$ are candidate critical points.

One can easily verify that

$$g_x(1,0) = 0 = g_y(1,0)$$

$$g_x(-1,0) = 0 = g_y(-1,0)$$

hence the points $(\pm 1,0)$ are actual critical points.

Similarly, suppose $(x,y)$ is a critical point with $y \ne 0$. Then

\begin{align*}
&y \ne 0\\[4pt]
\implies\; &3 - 2x^2 - 3y^2 = 0&&\text{[since $g_y = 0$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\; &2x^2 + 3y^2 = 3\\[4pt]
\implies\; &2x^2 + 3y^2 \ne 2\\[4pt]
\implies\; &2-2x^2 - 3y^2 \ne 0\\[4pt]
\implies\; &x = 0&&\text{[since $g_x = 0$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\; &3y^2 = 3&&\text{[since $2x^2 + 3y^2 = 3$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\; &y = \pm{1}\\[4pt]
\implies\; &(x,y) = (0,\pm{1})\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Thus, the points $(0,\pm 1)$ are candidate critical points.

One can easily verify that

$$g_x(0,1) = 0 = g_y(0,1)$$

$$g_x(0,-1) = 0 = g_y(0,-1)$$

hence the points $(0,\pm 1)$ are actual critical points.

So we have $5$ critical points, namely

$$(0,0),\;\;(\pm 1,0)\;\;(0,\pm 1)$$

Next, suppose $(x,y)$ is a point on the boundary of $\Delta$.

Then $x^2 + y^2 = 4$, hence

\begin{align*}
f(x,y) &= (2x^2 + 3y^2)e^{-x^2 - y^2}\\[4pt]
&=(2(x^2+y^2) + y^2)e^{-x^2 - y^2}\\[4pt]
&=(8 + y^2)e^{-4}&&\text{[since $x^2 + y^2 = 4$]}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

But for $(x,y) \in \Delta$, we have $x^2 + y^2 \le 4$, hence $0 \le y^2 \le 4$.

Thus, for a point $(x,y)$ on the boundary of $\Delta$,

\begin{align*}
&f(x,y) = (8 + y^2)e^{-4}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&8e^{-4} \le f(x,y) \le 12e^{-4}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Checking the values of $f$ at the $5$ critical points,

$\;\;\;{\small\bullet}\;$The minimum value of $f$ at the critical points is $0$, which occurs at $(0,0)$.

$\;\;\;{\small\bullet}\;$The maximum value of $f$ at the critical points is $3e^{-1}$, which occurs at $(0,\pm 1)$.

Since $0 < 8e^{-4}$ and $3e^{-1} > 12e^{-4}$, none of the boundary points qualify as candidates for points where $f$ has an absolute minimum or absolute maximum.

Thus, the absolute extreme values of $f$ on $\Delta$ are the minimum and maxiumum values of $f$ at the critical points, which have already been determined.

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort

Comment: @Reddevil: Did my answer resolve the issue?

Comment: Yea it just that I don't understand your approach on the system of equations I mean you state that since $g_x=0 $ you have that the whole eq is 0 and that implied that the second equation couldn't equal 3 which implied that y equal zero! I just didn't get how you arrived at this

Comment: If $g_x(x,y)= 0$, then either $x=0$ or $2 - 2x^2 - 3y^2 = 0$, agreed? 
$$$$
(if a product of two expressions is zero, at least one must be zero)

Comment: i do agree on that  i just thought that upvoting your comment will let you know that i agree on since the minimum number of chars to be written in a comment should be at least 15

Comment: So suppose $x \ne 0$. Then in that case, we must have $2-2x^2 - 3y^2 = 0$, or equivalently, $2x^2 + 3y^2 = 2$.

Comment: But if $2x^2 + 3y^2$ is equal to $2$, it can't be equal to $3$. Now look at $g_y(x,y)$ (which must also be zero, if $(x,y)$ is a critical point).

Comment: $x≠0$ then youll have that this whole thing not eq zero $2xe−x2−y2(2−2x2−3y2)$

Comment: No, if $x \ne 0$, the factor $(2 - 2x^2 - 3y^2)$ could be zero (and in fact, _must_ be zero).

Comment: of course.. youre right

Comment: So does that clear up the logic of the proof?

Comment: it does! how can i ever thank you man! you are awesome! thanks a lot for your time

Comment: The basic logic is that if $x \ne 0$, that forces $y=0$. Similarly, if $y \ne 0$, that forces $x=0$. Hence either $x=0$ or $y=0$, or both.

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to help.